# How do I run a function after registration in web2py?

Tags: web2py

Whenever I register a new user I want to populate a database with a default value. How do I run a function immediately after the user registers?

Thank you!

This is the table I want to populate. And I just want to fill the table with a 1 whenever a user registers.

```
db.define_table( 'test' , Field( 'num', 'double' , 
    requires=IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0, 1, dot=".", 
    error_message='Needs to be between 0 and 100') ) )

def user():
    return { 'form' : auth() }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a set of callbacks for the various Auth actions described in [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages) of the documentation. In this case:

```
auth.settings.register_onaccept.append(lambda form: db.test.insert(num=1))
```

`auth.settings.register_onaccept` is a list of callback functions. Each function takes the registration `SQLFORM` object after the new record has been inserted in the database. The new user ID will be in `form.vars.id`.